# How to access URL query string values in react router with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I have a URL as below with various querystring values.

```
http://localhost:3000/product/?id=123&name=test
```

I am working on isomorphic application using redux, react. So i am firing action and may i know how can i get these query string values to redux action file?

```
export function getProductData(params) {

  debug('Action Requested:' + params);  

  return {
    type:    GET_PRODUCT_DATA,
    promise: request.get(API_URL + params.productId)
  }
};
```

Because in action i am firing the API call and i need that ID from querystring value.

Comment: If You need to use response in action then dispatch in ajax callback not do promise in action. But I don't know if this is what You want to do.

Comment: This is isomorphic application, using this https://github.com/bananaoomarang/isomorphic-redux/tree/tutorial

Comment: My question is how to access the querystring values? if the url is like localhost:3000/product/1234, it is working as we code in the router like /product/:productid

Answer (score 2):

If you're using React-router, go ahead and access them via `props.location.query`

Would ultimately looks something like:

```
const Product = (props) =>
  <div>
     <button onClick={e => props.getProductData(props.location.query)}>Do Some Action</button>
  </div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters from the URL according to your routes are propagate to the component using `props.params`
so if you have routes like

```
<Route path="/product/:productid" component={Product} />
```

you can access productid from `Product` Component using props and pass it to your action:

```
const Product = (props) =>
  <div>
     <button onClick={e => props.getProductData(props.params)}>Do Some Action</button>
  </div>;
```

where `props.params` holds all the parameters you define in the route. in our case value of `productid` will be in `props.params.productid`.

Comment: are querystring also going to part of that? if you have just /product/ and the URL comes as /product/?id=1234

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question.  Does not mention usage of the query string at all.